# Hotkey on Windows 8 to move program to different monitor

Tags: windows-8, hotkeys

Is there a hotkey on windows 8 to move a program to a different monitor? My Primary screen does not always work so i cant see the program when it opens on that screen... solution?

Comment: If your primary screen doesn't work, how do you know the application is open

Answer (score 3):

Actually it's   `Win+Shift+Left/Right arrow`

Comment: This is the right answer to switch from one screen to another.

Answer (score 0):

If the focus is on the window you can move it with `WindowsKey + ArrowLeft/Right` until you see it.

Comment: And after that you can do `WindowsKey + ArrowUP` to make it full-screen again.

Comment: (Or just use the mouse then ;D)

Comment: That's also a possibility but if your hands are already on your keyboard it's easier to keep holding the `WindowsKey` and pressing `UP` (in my experience) :D